# Resize background image height on different screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

Please visit this site: http://www.themebia.com/pretavivre/

I'm using a slider for background images, the width of background images is 1920px in order to cover entire screen for 24" screens.

I think, the width of bg images are automatically resizing by browser but the height creates a vertical scroll bar and it is not good intention for user to scroll down for text box & footer area.

How can I manage the height of background images for different screens in order to fit the text box and footer area?

Should I use max-height property along with media quires to set max-height for images at certain break points?

Comment: you can try with fixed background image property... In any resolution BG Height & Width will be same...

Comment: @Saswata, Thanks. You can see, I"m not using the background css property. I'm using slider with image item. Can help with that?

Comment: Using @media query is also an option. but then you need to specify the height and width for different resolutions available.

Comment: @Saswata, Exactly, do you think this will be a good idea? Or any other good solution.

Comment: #home-container, #home-page-slides-wrapper make it as width:100%; .flexslider .slides img {height:auto;} DON'T put MAX-Height in .flexslider .slides img... In this case you may need to use higher resolution images...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this fixed background image :

```
.DivImage
{ 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please visit:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

Answer (score 0):

Set html and body height to 100%. Then add to #home-container

```
#home-container {
max-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

but, you'll have to change the position of .slide-desc otherwise it will be hidden.